# In magento admin how to create a custom field in add products page

Tags: magento

In my Magento admin add products page, I need to create a custom input field as subtitle for the product name. While adding products in Magento, we already have fields such as Name, Description, Short Description and so on. Among this I need to create a new field as Title to get the simple name of products. How do I create this custom field in admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create custom attribute for that .Follow this tutorial it may help you to create custom attribute. please have a look at a

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-attributes-work-in-magento

and

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields

Comment: By following this link i have created an attribute as title.That attribute was saved as attribute but it was not added in admin product page ..

Comment: can u explain how to do this?

Comment: i have done reindex.still the field is not added in product admin page

Comment: have you assign this attribute to Attribute set?

Comment: http://kb.retailvisibility.com/index.php?/article/AA-01352/0/Magento-Working-with-Product-Attribute-Sets.html follow this link

Comment: I have not done it.As you have mentioned in the link i have just created an attribute.what is the procedure to assign attribute?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42830/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-rama-priya)

Answer (score 2):

Find `manage attributes`, then add a new attribute. You can select its type. And then you can add this attribute to your `attribute set`. The `attribute set` which you are using, it may be default or any custom created. After adding you will find that attribute in your add Product page.